# Maven 3 on Windows7 64Bit

Tags: maven-3

I installed Maven3 on Win7 64Bit.

When I enter mvn in command prompt I get:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/classworlds/Launcher
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    Could not find the main class: org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.  Program will exit.

%JAVA-HOME% is an env variable.
%M2% is included in PATH

```
D:\Users\me>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26

D:\Users\me>echo %M2%
C:\TOOLS\maven-3.0.4\bin
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the maven binary from maven.apache.org ? and unpackaged it ? Have you tried just: mvn --version ?

Comment: what do you get when you go into this directory `C:\TOOLS\maven-3.0.4\bin` and run `mvn`

Comment: The problem was caused by an absolute path to a former maven installation in PATH ....this was used instead of %M2% everytiem typed "mvn"...So yes JoseK you pointed in the right direction ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What I do on windows 7 and 8 is set "M2_HOME" to my Maven directory which looks like this:

```
M2_HOME=E:\dev\tools\apache-maven-3.0.4
```

and then I add bin to my "PATH" and it works great!

```
Path=E:\dev\tools\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;
```

I think part of your problem is that you're setting "M2" and not "M2_HOME".

Answer (score 0):

I think you have downloaded the Source File and Not BINARY. You might be seeing Folders Starting with Apache-*** .

Download Binary file which has following folder structure

> Apache-Maven-3.3.9\bin+boot+conf+lib+licence....

Then set your

> M2_HOME=E:\dev\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9 
>   and
>   Path=E:\dev\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;

Hope this will work.